# XPath - get <img> that is not inside <a>

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

With XPath, how to select all the images that are not inside `<a>` tag?

For example, here:

```
<a href='foo'> <img src='bar'/> </a>
<img src='ham' />
```

I should get `"ham"` image as a result. To get the first image, I would use `\\a\\img`. Is there anything like `\\not(a)\\img` ?

I use python + lxml so python hacks are welcome, if pure xpath would be to hairy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easily done with

```
//img[not(ancestor::a)]
```

Read the spec on [XPath axes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#axes) if you want to find out about the other ones besides `ancestor`.